# The TextBox doesn't work inside Ajax UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, ajax

I had something very strange problem I added the Ajax **updatepanel** when
 firing button event to prevent the whole page from loading . I added
 the button event well but when I run debugger to chek the code
 processes the **textbox** return empty although I added the text . when I> tried to move the text box out the **updatepanel** the found that the
 button event cannot find the **textbox** control . so **what the problem ?**

```
<asp:DataList ID="DL_userpost" runat="server" CssClass="single-posts" RepeatColumns="1"
        OnItemCommand="DL_userpost_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="single-posts">
                <div class="post-user">
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="post-container-all">
                    <div class="post-user-single-img">
                        <asp:Image ID="Img_Twasol" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Post_File")%>' Width="130"
                            Height="99" /></div>
                    <div class="post-user-single-data-tabs">
                        <div class="post-user-single-data-title">
                            <%#Eval("User_Name")%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-user-single-data-text">
                            <%#Eval("Post_Content")%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="comment">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPPublicComment" runat="server" >
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:Panel ID="pnpublicpost" runat="server" DefaultButton="Btn_publicpost">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_publicpost" CssClass="comment-tabs2"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="Btn_publicpost" CommandName="publicpost" ValidationGroup="publicpost"
                                            runat="server" OnClick="Btn_publicpost_Click" Style="display: none" />
                                        <asp:Label ID="LblpublicpostPID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Post_ID")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
             </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: What code behind are you using to access TextBox?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into a new WebApplication Form, fired it up, Typed my name in the box and hit enter. The breakpoint on the method hit and my name was returned in txt_publicpost.Text

Answer (score 1):

I copied exactly your code from above to the Markup and made this method in the Code behind... your code looks fine

[image]

Comment: I don't think the poster wants to update the value. Or maybe I misread that. If he does, then yeah, he'll need to Set the UpdateMode to conditional and call an update.

Comment: I add the full aspx page , I noticed the problem with Datalist , but I donot why ?

Comment: @skdeveloper Yeah, once you use a DataList you'll need to use the OnCommand method. If you want to see what they typed in the box, it gets more complicated, you'll need to use jquery or something to get that value and set the command argument. What exactly do you want to do when they click enter on the comment box?

Answer (score 0):

Add `UpdateMode="Conditional"` in the `UpdatePanel`.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdInfo" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="TxtInfo" runat="server />
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: by default `updatemode` is `always`, so it refresh content on every postback

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't need to be conditional, unless you want to update it from the code behind

Comment: @MikeyMouse `conditional` only you want call `updatePanel.Update()`

Comment: I add the full aspx page , I noticed the problem with Datalist , but I donot why ?